# Redirect single page if browser is ie 8

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have a wordpress site and I need the homepage ONLY to be redirected to a different homepage if the browser is IE8.

This is what i have in the header, but, it redirects every page if someone is on ie8 because the header is on every page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE 8.0"))) {
  location.replace("http://website.com/ie8/");
}
-->
</script>
```

Since this is in the header, every page on my site gets redirected to website.com/ie8. I only need the homepage to do it. Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I would recommend you do redirection from PHP by using [get_browser()](https://www.php.net/get_browser) (or checking $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] directly) and then redirect as explained here: [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

That will be faster, more efficient, and more reliable than via js.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE 8.0") && window.location.pathname === '/') {
  location.replace("http://website.com/ie8/");
}
```